# QGIS - Rule based symbology, four symbologies from two fields with several acceptable values

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based

I have access to a remote service, with a polygon layer that i need to organize. The service is a REST service, and the setup of the data fails to load into QGIS (which is acceptable, as REST is proprietary) and a seek help organizing it in QGIS manually - from two columns i wish to sort out four symbologies, based on the first being a category, the next being age in years (string).

I have to two attributes in "buildings" and "age". For buildings, ~20 of them needs to be in one category, and some ~30 in the next. But for both i wish to group them further by "age" - and I'm not skilled in the expression topic.

For the first part a list of selections with "or" works fine. So a rule based symbology, with one symbology being selected on the following works:

```
"building"='ABC' or
"building"='ABX" or ...
```

But how i would go about grouping all these together for "if age >20" and "if age <20" i cannot get my head around.

**Edit:** So the groups should be:

```
Group A, under 20 years
Group A, over 20 years
Group B, under 20 years
Group B, over 20 years
```

And each group is first and foremost comprised of building as described above, so `"building"='ABC'` for where i have between 20-30 types of buildings for each group letter (A/B)

Comment: Please describe fully how your groups should be composed.

Comment: I tried - if i understood your comment correctly, you wanted a description of the end results, right?

Comment: Is it an option to add a field using field calculator? If yes, you can use the following formula to create your categories: concat(buildings,', ',if(age<20,'under 20 years','over 20 years'))

Comment: So, that's 4 rules you can simply create by chaining the two conditions with an `AND`. Have you tried doing so? If you did, and it didn't work, what exactly did you try?

Comment: @Erik I tried and in the very last part, but seeing you comment, should i try with an `and` for each line in the expression code, one for each building selection in between the `or` part?

Comment: @ThiPa I can see the field calculator can create a temporary layer, this might be a solution. However, i cannot edit the REST service, and i wish to have an updated dataset without manual interaction for each instance. I will try it, if i cannot get the symbologies to work.

Comment: Ah, you have several building strings... try `building IN ('Type A','Type B',...) AND "agecheck"`.

Comment: If the attributes from Building do not get changed so often => in the symbology interface: on top choose categorised, then insert the formula in the values field and on the bottom click classify. As formula, you'll need a mix of Erik's and mine: concat(if(building IN ('ABC', 'ABX', ...),'Group A ,','Group B ,'),if(age<20, 'under 20 years','over 20 years'))